# Does Nokia Java midlet app developed on S60 5th make comaptibility with S40 series?

Tags: java, java-me, nokia-s40, nokia-wrt

I have developed an J2ME Application(Midlets) using S60 5th series SDK. I want to make the app compatible with all Nokia mobile phones excluding Windows & Meego. I want to make sure that the app( jar file ) will run on all touch & non-touch nokia devices, if not then kindly notify how to make it compatible. I have tried it on touch device, it worked fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any S60's specific API means then it will not run in S40 device.Check the cofiguration of your j2me application such as Midp2.0,Midp1.0,etc.

Comment: Sir the Micro edition profile(MIDP) is set to 2.1. I have run it successfully on Nokia 202 i.e S40 device.